# How was this character allowed to keep his helmet in Deadpool 2?

Tags: marvel, x-men-cinematic-universe, deadpool, deadpool-2

How did Juggernaut still have his helmet while he was in prison?  When he escapes, he has his helmet on. I can’t believe they would have just let him keep it on while there, or would bring it with them during the transport. Was there any explanation of how/why he still had it?

Comment: Hey guys! We’ve got a volunteer to try taking Juggernaut’s helmet off again! Good luck fella!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It probably falls under "personal effects" which by law have to be housed and transported with inmates in most jurisdictions so they're available immediately when the person is released.

Comment: "Congratulations on your release. Here you have your knives, crowbar, glass cutters and grapple hook back. Stay out of trouble now. Bye bye."

Comment: @LVDV Yup pretty much, there was a murder not too long ago committed by a freshly released prisoner who had been given back the gun as a personal effect, in theory so he could sell it to help cover his legal fees; in reality he went and shot his ex-wife instead.

Comment: With the way the IceBox and the orphanage work, I'm pretty surprised they cared about personal effects.

Comment: In the Marvel Universe in general, they may house these items in a special, easily accessible area, to cut down on the number of guards killed during each escape. :-)

Answer (score 1):

As [his armor is magnetic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/195083/5789), they probably used human tech to bring him in, and had no need to risk their lives removing his helmet.